# List.dropLast() is returning an Empty List

Tags: android, list, kotlin

I am working on a dictionary app that has this DAO Query which is returning 20 items from the Database. The query is working fine.

```
@Query("SELECT word, meanings FROM wordentity GROUP BY word ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 20")
    suspend fun getLastTenWords(): List<Words>
```

In the ViewModel I pass the list of words from the DB to a helper method to tidy up the list i.e. remove duplicates, remove caps and just return the first 10 cleaned items.

```
private fun cleanLastTenWords(words: List<Word>): List<String> {
        
        val list = mutableListOf<String>()

        for (word in words) {

            list.add(word.word.lowercase())

        }

        return list.distinct()
                .dropLast(10)}
```

The Database ***starts with zero items*** but when a user searches the dictionary the word is inserted into database.

The issue is that **an empty list is being returned initially until 11 items have been inserted**. At the 11th Item, a list of 1 word item is returned. At the 12th Item, the DB returns a list of 2 word items and so on.

The issue is being caused by `dropLast()` call. This is because when I comment out `dropLast(10)` the code works fine but it is returning ***more than 10*** word items.

What I need is just a list of the first 10 word items - for instance, if the DB has 3 items it should just return 3 items instead of returning an empty list. If the list has 15 Items, I need just the first ten items and discard anything else after the 10th item.

Where I'm going wrong?

Comment: I think you wanted to write `return list.distinct().take(10)` so to keep the first 10 elements. Isn't this what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: `take(10)` works just fine, Thanks very much @F.Mysir, you are a legend!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest answer was `return list.distinct().take(10)` thanks to F.Mysir's comment above.

Alternatively use `if-else` to check the number of items contained in the list.

```
private fun cleanLastTenWords(words: List<Word>): List<String> {
        
        val list = mutableListOf<String>()

        for (word in words) {

            list.add(word.word.lowercase())

        }

     /*return list.distinct().take(10)*/

        return if (list.size > 10) 

               list.distinct().dropLast(10) 

               else 

               list.distinct()

    }
```

Comment: You should probably mention that this alternative will return no more than 10 elements specifically if you have 20 elements at most. If you get 30 in, this will return 20. I'd say this is quite specific alternative which is too narrow and won't really help many, and is unnecessary given the direct and simple solution.